# Falcon parsing json error

Tags: python, python-3.x, falconframework

I'm trying out Falcon for a small api project. Unfortunate i'm stuck on the json parsing stuff and code from the documentation examples does not work.

I have tried so many things i've found on Stack and Google but no changes.
I've tried the following codes that results in the errors below

```
import json
import falcon

class JSON_Middleware(object):
    def process_request(self, req, resp):
       raw_json = json.loads(req.stream.read().decode('UTF-8'))
       """Exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'"""

       raw_json = json.loads(req.stream.read(), 'UTF-8')
       """Exception: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'"""

       raw_json = json.loads(req.stream, 'UTF-8')
       """TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'Body'"""
```

I'm on the way of giving up, but if somebody can tell me why this is happening and how to parse JSON in Falcon i would be extremely thankful.

Thanks

Environment:
OSX Sierra
Python 3.5.2
Falcon and other is the latest version from Pip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code should work if other pieces of code are in place . a quick test(filename app.py):

```
import falcon
import json

class JSON_Middleware(object):
    def process_request(self, req, resp):
       raw_json = json.loads(req.stream.read())
       print raw_json

class Test:
    def on_post(self,req,resp):
        pass

app = application = falcon.API(middleware=JSON_Middleware())
t = Test()
app.add_route('/test',t)
```

run with: `gunicorn app`
`$ curl -XPOST 'localhost:8000' -d '{"Hello":"wold"}'`

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response. The example is pretty much what i had, but did a copy paste witch resulted in "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'". Tested on Ubuntu in a VM and it worked fine. This is strange. Tried to reinstall but not did not help. Ideas ? :-)

Comment: @Audunfr if you find this answer correct then accept it .

Answer (score 1):

You have to invoke `encode()` on the bytes returned by `read()` with something like `req.stream.read().encode('utf-8')`.

This way the bytes are converted to a str as expected by `json.loads()`.

The other way not to bother with all this boring and error prone encode/decode and bytes/str stuff (which BTW differs in Py2 and Py3), is to use simplejson as a replacement for json. It is API compatible, so the only change is to replace `import json` with `import simplejson as json` in your code.

In addition, it simplifies the code since reading the body can be done with `json.load(req.bounded_stream)`, which is much shorter and more readable than `json.loads(req.bounded_stream.read().encode('utf-8'))`.

I now do it this way, and don't use the standard json module any more.